# Newtonsoft.Json custom object collection deserializer

Tags: c#, .net, json, datetime, serialization

Is there any way to specify custom deserialization for collection of objects but only for dates?

Here is what do i mean:

Let's say I have collection of objects - it could be any object and json deserialized them pretty good. Everything is fine instead of dates.

```
public List<object> Values { get; set; }
```

I don't want to set any properties globally - but only for this property. If there is a DateTime in collection of Values - I want to deserialize it in my own way (e.g. without time).

What can you suggest me?

Globally i use this settings:

```
var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
{
   DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat, 
   DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc                     
};
```

Use Case:

For instance I have such structure:

```
{
  "Intance": 1,
  "Values": [
    "Ivan",
    "488-555-1212",
    "United States",
    {
      "ShortDesc": "NY",
      "LongDesc": "New York"
    },
    "1985-05-01T00:00:00-05:00"
  ],
  "LastUpdated": "2017-02-06T22:11:34-05:00"
}
```

Let's say - it is birthdate -

*"1985-05-01T00:00:00-05:00".*

E.g. Web Services time zone - **Eastern Time: -5**.

My time zone is **Central Time (US): -6**.

In this case I will get: **1985-04-30** - It is day behind. 
It is right, but I don't need such behavior, because it is my birthday and it shouldn't take into account time zones.

LastUpdated property will deserialize correctly.

Comment: I would serialize it as `DateTime` and either (a) pass the result into a converter method/constructor for your struct/type or (b) ignore the time part of the DateTime by defining your own comparison and using format operators when displaying it.  Why do you want to serialize it without time?

Comment: e.g. it is BirthDate... i don't need date time for it.

Comment: That's a good question. I was actually thinking about something like that earlier today. Let's say the server returns the time in UTC. How would I go about automatically converting it to local time on client-side while deserializing the JSON to the object?

Comment: Cab you modify your data model to add [serialization attributes](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)?

Comment: yes, i can... but i need that these attributes took affect only for dates in this collection. All other types should be serialized and desiarialized in a standard way

Comment: @IvanSalo @Reynevan Using `[OnDeserialized]` as @dbc provided, you can modify your DateTime to have zero hours/minutes/seconds or convert it to another class.  You can also convert it from UTC to system time there.

Comment: @LukeSamuel Hey, thanks! That's really useful

Comment: Check out the [JsonConverterAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) and the [JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) classes. They may be what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried that, but I don't want to replace standart conversion of other types. Can I apply this attribute just for DateTime object in collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work by adding custom contract resolver and custom attribute. So when resolver sees that attribute it deserializes date as expected.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class IgnoreTimeZoneAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class IgnoreTimeZonePropertyResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> props = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        foreach (JsonProperty prop in props)
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop.UnderlyingName);

            if (pi != null && pi.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(IgnoreTimeZoneAttribute), true) != null)
            {
                prop.ValueProvider = new IgnoreTimeZoneValueProvider(pi);
            }
        }

        return props;
    }

    public class IgnoreTimeZoneValueProvider : IValueProvider
    {
        private PropertyInfo _targetProperty;

        public IgnoreTimeZoneValueProvider(PropertyInfo targetProperty)
        {
            this._targetProperty = targetProperty;
        }

        // GetValue is called by Json.Net during serialization.
        public object GetValue(object target)
        {
            return _targetProperty.GetValue(target);
        }

        // SetValue gets called by Json.Net during deserialization.
        // The value parameter has the value/values read from the JSON;
        // target is the object on which to set the value/values without TimeZone info.
        public void SetValue(object target, object value)
        {
            var newValue = value;

            if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(_targetProperty.PropertyType))
            {
                IList<object> values = value as IList<object>;

                if (values != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < values.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        var curValue = values[i];
                        if (curValue != null && curValue.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                        {
                            DateTimeOffset dateTime = new DateTimeOffset((DateTime)curValue);
                            values[i] = dateTime.UtcDateTime.Date;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            _targetProperty.SetValue(target, newValue);
        }
    }
}
```